# Object allocation in objective c

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
-(NSMutableArray*)functionCheck :(NSString *)str
{
    NSMutableArray*d2=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"check address::::::> %p",&d2);
    [d2 insertObject:str atIndex:0];
    return  d2;
}

-(NSString*)functionTest :(NSString *)str
{
    NSMutableArray *arr1=[self functionCheck :@"dee"];
    NSMutableArray *arr2=[self functionCheck :@"deep"];
    NSMutableArray *arr3=[self functionCheck :@"deepti"];
}
```

It allocates same memory location whenever the function is called (`arr1`,`arr2` and `arr3` point to the same object).

How to create new object of `NsMutableArray` whenever this method is called?

Comment: Not `NsMutableArray` but `NSMutableArray`...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Not clear to me what's your goal...

Comment: the printed &d2 is a pointer to the pointer on the stack. This will usually be the same value. Print only d2 instead.

Comment: create new object of NSMutableArray, whenever function is called.

Comment: This is the same as your previous question [object reference is same in function calling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653972/object-reference-is-same-in-function-calling), for which you got 3 answers. If you think that those answers do not solve the problem, you should leave a comment or improve the question, instead of posting the same question again.

Comment: @MartinR only one of the three answers to that other question is correct.

Answer (score 3):

That code creates you a new array each time you invoke the method. The problem is this line:

```
NSLog(@"check address::::::> %p",&d2);
```

You are logging the address of d2 which is a location on the stack.  You need to log d2 itself because d2 is already a pointer.

```
NSLog(@"check address::::::> %p",d2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the address with &d2 but should send the object instead like:

```
NSLog(@"check address: %p", d2);
```